# how to show start point to end point route on leaflet map with all marker which lat long commung from api in agular13

Tags: angular, angular12, angular13

for example we have one bus the route is fix in that route all Bus stand covered by marker how can we do in angular with leaflet map which is show in image[image]

Answer (score 0):

u can use @angular/google-maps

html

```
 <google-map [center]="center"
              [zoom]="zoom">

    <map-marker *ngFor="let markerPosition of markerPositions"
                [position]="markerPosition"
                [options]="markerOptions"></map-marker>

    <map-polyline [path]="vertices"></map-polyline>

  </google-map>
```

ts

```
public center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: 13, lng: 13 };
  public zoom = 4;
  public markerPositions: google.maps.LatLngLiteral[] = [
    { lat: 13, lng: 13 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 12 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 11 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 10 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 9 },
    { lat: -13, lng: 0 },
    { lat: 13, lng: -13 },
  ];
  public markerOptions: google.maps.MarkerOptions = { draggable: false };

  public vertices: google.maps.LatLngLiteral[] = [
    { lat: 13, lng: 13 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 12 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 11 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 10 },
    { lat: 13, lng: 9 },
    { lat: -13, lng: 0 },
    { lat: 13, lng: -13 },
  ];
```

check this link [Use Google Maps](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component#loading-the-maps-javascript-api) to see how u create a Key and load the maps API